# $u: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$: does bounded and uniformly continuous imply Lipschitz?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

Let $u: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$: if $u$ is bounded and uniformly continuous, then is it Lipschitz continuous? Or is it at least locally Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: No, continuous functions are not automatically locally Lipschitz.

Comment: What does locally Lipschitz mean?

Comment: @zhw Every point $x$ has a neighbourhood $U$ such that $\left.f\right\rvert_U$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks. Then there are bounded uniformly continuous functions that are nowhere locally Lipschitz.

Answer (score 3):

Take

- $n=1$
- $f(x)=\arcsin(x)$

$f$ is continuous at $[-1,1]$, thus it is uniformly continuous by Heine's Theorem. Also,  it is bounded .

But it is not Lipschitz cause its derivative $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ is not bounded.

Answer (score 2):

No, consider the function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined as $f(x)=\min(1,\sqrt{|x|})$. This function is not locally lipschitz at $0$.

Comment: Can we at least conclude that $u$ is locally Lipshitz?

Comment: no, in this example the function is not locally Lipschitz at $0$.

Comment: Maybe can we say that bounded and uniformly continuous imply absolutely continuous?

Comment: @Axel No, take the Weierstrass function $W$ on $[0,1]$ We can assume $W(0)=W(1).$ Then we can extend $W$ to all of $\mathbb R$ by periodicity. This is bounded and uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$ and differentiable nowhere.

Comment: This example is also not absolutely continuous. To prove it you need to use that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i}$ diverges while $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}$ converges.

Comment: @zhw. And if we also assume piecewise linear with finitely many discontinuities of the derivative?

Comment: @axel, that one obviously works, you meay want to post on a seperate question.

Comment: This $f$ certainly is absolutely continuous: For $x\ge 0, f(x) = \int_0^x (1/2)t^{-1/2}\chi_{[0,1]}(t)\,dt.$ Same idea on the other side.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo, good idea: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066456/u-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-does-continuous-and-piecewise-linear-imply-absol

Comment: @zhw. it is not absolutely continuous. Take the intervals $[0,a/j^2]$ for $j$ between $1$ and $m$, and $a$ sufficiently small. If you meke $m$ large enough you can make the sum of its roots go to infinity, while leaving the interval-length sum bounded by $\pi^2a/6$.

Comment: @Jorge Fernández Hidalgo On $[0,1]$ $\sqrt x$ is the indefinite integral of an $L^1$ function, so is absolutely continuous. I don't know what roots you are talking about.

Comment: Oh ok, I just learned absolute continutity, I forgot to add the assumption that the intervals must be pairwise disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $$f(x) = \tan^{-1}(\sqrt[3]x)$$
$f(x)$ is bounded and uniformly continuous but is not Lipschitz.

None of the earlier answers are bijective functions from $\Bbb R^1 \to \Bbb R$; this one is.

Comment: this function isn't bounded

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Yes it is.

Comment: This is not a bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R.$

Comment: Ok, I didn't actually look at the function, but being bijective and bounded are exclusive right?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Yes, I said the same thing above.