# $u: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$: does continuous and piecewise linear imply absolutely continuous (or more)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $u: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. If $u$ is continuous and piecewise linear (with a finite number of discontinuities of the derivative), then is it absolutely continuous (or more)?

Comment: It's Lipschitz!

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to prove over induction on the number of breakpoints that $f(x)-f(y)=\int\limits_x^y f_{-}'(t)dt$.

Now, let $\alpha=\max\{|f'_-(x)|  | x\in \mathbb R\}$.

Now take $x<y$, we have  $|f(x)-f(y)|=|\int\limits_{x}|f'(t)dt|\leq \int\limits_x^y |f'(t)dt|\leq \alpha|x-y|$.

So the function is Lipschitz continuous with constant $\alpha$.